# What is the exact benefit and usage of "Spin Identity"?

Tags: the-strange

In the strange, Spin identity is a twist a spinner can use to convince intelligent creatures that you are someone else. Its a relatively expensive use of your intellect pool. Disguises can be an asset to the relevant roll.

How is using this mechanically different than a normal persuasion attempt, which any one could try as an Intellect task aided by, perhaps, persuasion training? Does Spin Identity provide a reduction in difficulty? Or, does it allow you to convince people of your identity in normally impossible situations?

I get the idea here: the spinner is really good at fooling people. I'm just a little confused how the Spin Identity twist is suppose to be applied mechanically. I want to make sure spinners feel that they can do something cool and unique, and something that is worth the Intellect pool cost of 2+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, Spin Identity is useful in situations where a regular persuasion attempt would take too much time or resources. Of course, you *could* try and persuade everyone that your plastic badge is the real deal the hard way - but with the supernatural power of Spin Identity, the target just glosses over some of the more obvious weak spots of your disguise.

Of course, if you are always able to come up with good disguises, explanations and excuses, you may not need it after all.

On the other hand, 2+ isn't *that* high of a cost: at first tier you already have an Intellect edge of 1, so it's only a minimum of 1 point from your pool, which you should be able to afford easily. Those pool points are meant to be spent, after all.